# Why do I get an invalid-session redirect after a Spring Security logout?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC project which uses Spring Security. I am wondering how `j_spring_security_logout` works. I have a logout link defined in a view like this:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">Logout</a>
```

In my `spring-security.xml` I have defined this:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/wellcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"  />
<logout logout-success-url="/logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
<session-management invalid-session-url="/invalidsession" />
```

I expected that clicking logout should redirect me to `/logout`, but instead I get redirected to the `invalid-session-url`, namely `/invalidsession`. The `logout-success-url` is ignored.

However when I delete `session-management`, logging out does indeed redirect me to `/logout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [Spring Security reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt).

You can't really use the session-expiry facility unless the session cookie is deleted when you log out.

Answer (score 0):

Use just this one and it should work (without `logout-url`):

```
<logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
```

I think you may experience problems by using both logout and session management invalid session url because once you've logged out your session is no longer valid.

**Update per your additional question, how about this :**

```
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout?displayLogout=1" />
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/logout?displayLogout=0" />
```

<strike>And then in your view :</strike>

```
<c:if test="${param.displayLogout == 0}">
    <h2>Your session has timed out.</h2>
</c:if>
```

**Update #2,** just tried it locally, when you logout your session is invalid and you get redirected to `invalid-session-url` location you specified in the `session-management` configuration.

Really interested in the solution now.

Comment: Without `logout-url` the result is still the same. According to your second sentence: in which way can I inform user about expired session without `session-management`?

Comment: Thank you, but in this way also after logging out user will see the message: `Your session has timed out.`. I would like to distinguish when session has expired and logging out action.

Comment: @woyaru you can put else and you get your distinct message

Comment: Yes of course, but always after logging out action user will see the message about session not about that he has just logged out.

Comment: It doesn't have to be just message, you can display one html page for log out and another for session expired. Just using this if/else, but it's up to you I'd like to see how you solve this, quite interesting. This was just something on top of my head.

Comment: I have written something like that in my question. But it isn't working and this is my problem I have described. Logging out action redirects me to `invalid-session-url` despite it is `/logout?displayLogout=0` or my `/invalidsession`.